# Resume another application from the background

Tags: android

I am trying to resume another another android application from the background programmatically. Is it possible ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just launch another app.

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(another app packagename)
```

start this intent.
(you can also use intent by URI .And make sure suitable lauchmode)

Comment: But this will launch another instance of the app. It want resume it ?

Comment: I thought that it is going to create a new Intent but it worked and resumed the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like: when user presses home or back button your application launches another application, then you can use onStop() or onPause() methods.